# Use Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu as context menu for multilevel asp grid

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 and Asp.net gridview. I have created a context menu for  my gridview using this solution [example in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/X9tgY/)

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover">
```

My question is that I have a nested grid or a multi level grid. i want to have a different context menu for each level. is this possible with this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have different context menus for different tables on your page, it's just a matter of how you handle it.

Here are two options, one simple and one a bit more sophisticated.

**1: Multiple selectors**

Simply change the jQuery selector on which you call `contextMenu`.
Here is an example which shows a different context menu for the first table and the second nested table: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly_cardinal/46sHX/1/

```
// Only add this context menu to cells that are
// a direct descendent of #myTable
$("#myTable > tbody > tr > td").contextMenu({
    menuSelector: "#contextMenu",
    menuSelected: function (invokedOn, selectedMenu) {
        var msg = "You selected the menu item '" + selectedMenu.text() +
            "' on the value '" + invokedOn.text() + "'";
        alert(msg);
    }
});

// Only add this context menu to cells that are in a table
// that is nested inside #myTable
$("#myTable td > table td").contextMenu({
    menuSelector: "#contextMenu2",
    menuSelected: function (invokedOn, selectedMenu) {
        var msg = "You selected the menu item '" + selectedMenu.text() +
            "' on the value '" + invokedOn.text() + "'";
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

---

**2: Dynamic menuSelector**

The more sophisticated option requires a change to your context menu plugin to allow the `menuSelector` property to be a function that receives the clicked element and returns the selector of the context menu that should be shown.

Here's the altered `contextMenu` plugin:

```
(function ($, window) {

    $.fn.contextMenu = function (settings) {

        return this.each(function () {
            var selector;

            // Open context menu
            $(this).on("contextmenu", function (e) {
                selector = $(getMenuSelector(e, settings.menuSelector))

                //open menu
                $(selector)
                    .data("invokedOn", $(e.target))
                    .show()
                    .css({
                        position: "absolute",
                        left: getLeftLocation(e, selector),
                        top: getTopLocation(e, selector)
                    });

                //add click listener on menu
                ContextMenuClickHandler();

                return false;
            });

            // click handler for context menu
            function ContextMenuClickHandler() {
                $(selector)
                    .off('click')
                    .on( 'click', function (e) {
                        $(this).hide();

                        var $invokedOn = $(this).data("invokedOn");
                        var $selectedMenu = $(e.target);

                        settings.menuSelected.call($(this), $invokedOn, $selectedMenu);
                });

            }

            //make sure menu closes on any click
            $(document).click(function () {
                $(selector).hide();
            });
        });

        function getMenuSelector(e, menuSelector){
            var selector = menuSelector;
            if ($.isFunction(menuSelector)){
                selector = menuSelector.call(null, e);
            }
            return selector;
        }

        function getLeftLocation(e, selector) {
            var mouseWidth = e.pageX;
            var pageWidth = $(window).width();
            var menuWidth = $(selector).width();

            // opening menu would pass the side of the page
            if (mouseWidth + menuWidth > pageWidth &&
                menuWidth < mouseWidth) {
                return mouseWidth - menuWidth;
            } 
            return mouseWidth;
        }        

        function getTopLocation(e, selector) {
            var mouseHeight = e.pageY;
            var pageHeight = $(window).height();
            var menuHeight = $(selector).height();

            // opening menu would pass the bottom of the page
            if (mouseHeight + menuHeight > pageHeight &&
                menuHeight < mouseHeight) {
                return mouseHeight - menuHeight;
            } 
            return mouseHeight;
        }

    };
})(jQuery, window);

$("#myTable td").contextMenu({
    menuSelector: function(e){
        // Do something with the clicked element to work out what to show
        var selector = "#contextMenu";
        if ($(e.target).closest('table').is('table table')){
            selector = '#contextMenu2';
        }
        return selector;
    },
    menuSelected: function (invokedOn, selectedMenu) {
        var msg = "You selected the menu item '" + selectedMenu.text() +
            "' on the value '" + invokedOn.text() + "'";
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

And here's a fiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly_cardinal/d8EfA/

I'd recommend going through the original and the altered version to see how it works.